# How to transfer value from Vuex Store to i18n.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-i18n

I am trying to make the language that I chose was saved when the program was restarted.

How to save the value of **locale:''** in **i18n** when switching languages?

I want to transfer this value from VUEX Store to i18n, but I don’t know how to do  it right.

The default **local:** 'en'.
When the language is changed, the value in locale is overwritten and stored in **localStorage**, and when the program is restarted, the value at the **created ()** stage is taken from **localStorage**.

Maybe at least an example exists where a similar function is implemented?

```
<template>
...
             <f7-menu-dropdown-item href="#" @click="setLocale('en')">
             <f7-menu-dropdown-item href="#" @click="setLocale('ru')">    
...
</template>

export default {
methods: {
    setLocale(locale){
      import(`../langs/${locale}.json`).then((msgs) => {
        this.$i18n.setLocaleMessage(locale, msgs)
        this.$i18n.locale = locale
        localStorage.setItem('language', locale);
  })
},
        created(){
      if(localStorage.getItem('language') !== null){
         localStorage.setItem('language', navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);
       }

}
}
}
```

**i18n.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueI18n from 'vue-i18n'
import en from '../langs/en.json'
import ru from '../langs/ru.json'
Vue.use(VueI18n)

export const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: window.localStorage.getItem("language"),
    fallbackLocale: 'ru',
    messages:{
        en,
        ru
    }
})
```

Comment: Vuex doesn't persist your states.

Comment: Where did I make a mistake? How to do right?

Comment: Well you have two options. You can use vuex-persist but in your case the localstorage is the correct place to store this. `locale: window.localStorage.getItem("language")`

Comment: Tell me please. How now to install the application language by system language.  I try like this         `created(){
      if(localStorage.getItem('language') !== null){
         localStorage.setItem('language', navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage);
       }`

Comment: `navigator.systemLanguage`, `navigator.browserLanguage`, `navigator.userLanguage`